# Rails 3- Show destroy error in index page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model called department that has many users.
I created a before_destroy method to check if a department has users associated to it, in that case it should not be deleted.

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_destroy :without_users 
   has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy

   def without_users
      if self.users.size() > 0
         self.errors.add :base, "The department cannot be deleted because it has users associated to it"
      end
      self.errors.blank?
   end
end
```

In my index view I have a button that destroys the department.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("remove.png", :border => 0, :title => 'Delete'), department, confirm: 'Are you sure that you want to delete?', method: :delete, :class=>"actions_table" %>
```

And in my controller this is my destroy action:

```
def destroy
   @department = Department.find(params[:id])
   @department.destroy

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to departments_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
   end
end
```

What is the Rails way to show the error message in the index view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you pass error messsages to display on the view using `flash` variables.  [See the documentation for it here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash).  This would be useful in a scenario where you were redirecting.  Alternatively you could use the `render` command to render a page which can actually grab the `@department` object from this request and then access the `errors` attribute.

If you're trying to display all the error messages for a user, I might suggest taking your destroy action and doing this.

```
def destory
  @department = Department.find(params[:id])
  @department.destroy

  unless @department.errors
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to departments_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  else
    # here is where you handle the scenario where there are errors.
    render 'error_page'
  end
end
```

Comment: How can I concatenate all my errors in @department.errors and show it in a flash variable?

Comment: The RoR tutorial by Michael Hartl has a really good description for how to make a partial that's good for rendering multiple error messages when an object has errors.  [Check this section out, should help you](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec:signup_error_messages).

Comment: This is just an update to Batkins post. The url is now this http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-signup_error_messages